# C# Get Javascript Cookies with HttpClient

Tags: c#, cookies, httpclient

I'm trying to get the cookies from here: https://www.etoro.com/people/wesl3y/portfolio
If I call the Webpage with my Edge Browser, there are a lot of cookies, which are not flagged as "HTTP". For example the follwing cookie:

> TMIS2 9a74f8b353780f2fbe59d8dc1d9cd901437be0b823f8ee60d0ab3637053d1bd9675fd2caa6404a74b4fc2a8779e1e7d486862875b11af976466a696de4a89c87e0e942f11ceed91c952d629646dc9cb71bdc2c2fd95a0a71698729f733717a775675add1a06bd9883e47c30e3bd162fabd836467a1cc16870a752373581adfd2ca  .etoro.com  /   2021-03-20T17:40:43.000Z    263             Medium

I want to get this cookie in my c# Program via HttpClient also, but until now I don't know how :( As far as I understood this cookies are not accessed via http, else Javascript is used to set this cookies on clientside.

Currently I used the following code for accessing the page and show the found cookies:

```
   public void Test()
    {
        CookieContainer CookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler
        {
            CookieContainer = CookieJar,
            UseCookies = true,
        };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
        
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://www.etoro.com/people/wesl3y/portfolio").Result;

        Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.etoro.com/people/wesl3y/portfolio");
        IEnumerable<Cookie> responseCookies = CookieJar.GetCookies(uri).Cast<Cookie>();
        foreach (Cookie cookie in responseCookies)
            Console.WriteLine(cookie.Name + ": " + cookie.Value);
    }
```

With my code I got all Cookies with Parameter HTTP=true, but miss all the other ones. Is there a way to get the missing cookies from that site with HttpClient? Or is there any other type of c# integrated Browser i have to use? The Main focus of my Tool is getting Json Information from the etoro.com API. But the API Access is very Rate limited when the right cookies are not in place :(

Thanks, Mag.

Comment: Sounds like the cookies are set via script. To get them, you’ll need to run the script, which is not trivial. You’ll need to emulate the browser itself, e.g. use a tool like Selenium.

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look on it!

Comment: I have some complex solution on [RU StackOverlow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1217351/373567) for parsing with auth. `CookieContainer` isn't simple.

Comment: In short, `HttpClient` by default handle cookies like a browser following HTTP standard. The issue is load/save cookies when needed that i solved with hacking `CookieContainer` using Reflection. Selenium is tool for browser automation testing (Web site QA). It's too slow and heavy for parsing or getting access to web sites. I don't recommend it for such purpose.